# how do I get monthly 3rd Fri and quarterly 3rd Fri

Tags: kdb

I am stuck with the logic on writing a function to accept startdate & enddate and give all the dates which is 3rd Fri and similar function to give quarterly 3rd Fri

```
thirdFridays[2019.01.01;2019.12.31]
//return all 3rd Friday date list 
quarterlyThirdFridays[2019.01.01;2019.12.31]
//return all quarterly 3rd friday date list
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function will get the Xth weekday of a month:

```
q)XthWeekdayofMonth:{[d;n;m]((),o)where(),m="m"$o:(7*$[all n;n-1;til 5])+t+(d-t:"d"$m)mod 7};
```

So with friday=6 and running it over a range of months:

```
q)XthWeekdayofMonth[6;3;]each 2019.01m+til 12
2019.01.18
2019.02.15
2019.03.15
2019.04.19
2019.05.17
2019.06.21
2019.07.19
2019.08.16
2019.09.20
2019.10.18
2019.11.15
2019.12.20
```

You could extend it to quarters pretty easily by just supplying the relevant month in each quarter

Comment: Awesome Terry, that is exactly what I was looking for. Very gracefully done.
Can you please help me understand the code logic?

Comment: The function is more general than your particular use case but essentially it gets the first day of the month and corrects it to the first day you've specified. e.g. `{f+x-(f:"d"$y)mod 7}[6;2023.01m]` snaps 2023.01.01 to the first friday. Then it just adds multiples of 7 to get second friday, third friday etc